# Custom Validation not working Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, twitter

I am trying to validate a users twitter username and have written a custom validation. However it is not working even though it appears to work for in a irb session. This is the code I have

```
    def twitter_user                    
        begin 
            @t = Twitter.user :twitter
        rescue Twitter::Error::NotFound => e
            @t = nil
        end 

        errors.add(:twitter, (" username does not exist")) if @t.nil?

    end
```

I've also tried this:

```
def twitter_user

            errors.add(:twitter, (" username does not exist")) unless begin Twitter.user :twitter
            rescue Twitter::Error::NotFound => e

            end 

        end
```

This error appears even when the twitter username is valid. Can anyone explain why? Help would be appreciated thanks.

EDIT: I have narrowed it down to the param getting passed :twitter, is not the input from the user. How do I get the value passed by the user?

Comment: `begin; Twitter.user :twitter; rescue Twitter::Error::NotFound; errors.add(:twitter, "username does not exist"); end`

Comment: This ends up with the same problem. I wonder if there is something I'm overlooking. Just seeing as it works in the irb session I'm confused.

Comment: Try errors.add_to_base("username does not exist").. this will add error to object.. For specific field errors.add(:twitter, "username does not exist" ). I hope this code is in model

Comment: Thanks, but that also does not work.

Comment: Looks to me like you are looking for a twitter account with the name 'twitter'. Is that really what you wanted?

Comment: Yea I just solved it. If I search for twitter instead of :twitter it works. You can give an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add validate method in you model

for ex:

```
validate :user_is_exist


def user_is_exist
  errors.add(:twitter, (" username does not exist")) if @t.nil?
end
```